# How to export a PNG with an alpha channel?

Tags: export, image

Is "RGBA" not a supported colorspace?

```
Export["test.png", RandomImage[1, {100, 100}], ColorSpace -> "RGBA"]
```

Comment: `Export["~/Desktop/a.png", Graphics[Circle[]], Background -> None]` ? Or [add an alpha channel](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAlphaChannel.html) to the `Image` before exporting.

Comment: @Szabolcs that works, but still kind of weird that RGBA isn't a valid `ColorSpace` you know?